# Write tag and remove with jQuery Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Good morning all,
I want to create a little bit js code for phpbb forum, I want to create a button, when it's clicking create code `[media][/media]` the problem is, i can't do Toggle, when button clicking must be create `[media][/media]` after when again click delete `[media][/media]` My code:

```js
var textForMedia = "Input your media link";
$('a').click(function() //this will apply to all anchor tags
{ 
   $( ".inner" ).wrapInner( "[media]" + textForMedia + "[/media]");
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <a href="#">Input video</a>
  <textarea style="width:300px;height:200px" placeholder="Media" class="inner"></textarea>
</form>
```

P.S. and how do array `textForMedia` disappearing    `$(textForMedia).fadeToggle('slow', 'linear');` like this?

P.S.S. sorry for my english )

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of many things as follows.

On click of `a` you add `filled` class to `textarea`. On `click` again check for the `filled` class and do `toggle` behavior.

```js
var textForMedia = "Input your media link";
$('a').click(function() //this will apply to all anchor tags
  {
    if( $(".inner").hasClass("filled"))
    {
      $(".inner").empty();
      $(".inner").removeClass("filled");
    }
     else{
       $(".inner").text("[media]" + textForMedia + "[/media]");
      $(".inner").addClass("filled");
    }
  });
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <a href="#">Input video</a>
  <textarea style="width:300px;height:200px" placeholder="Media" class="inner"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: not exactly :( If user want write something and after wanna put the media.. Script will not work :( Even then my example will not work